# Как избавиться от черных ромбов со знаками вопроса в логах ошибок?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Например, получаю такую ошибку:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "Mixa" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
```

Хотелось бы чтобы вместо знаков ромба был нормальный текст. Я так понимаю дело в кодировке, но как исправить не знаю. Использую ОС - win 10.

**UPD**

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db 
name=postgres
password=postgres
```

Comment: У Вас ромбы только в ошибках с подключением к PostgreSQL возникают или же в других исключениях(в которых предполагается локализованный текст на русском) тоже?

Comment: Только с Postgres

Comment: свойства подключения приложите, пожалуйста

Comment: driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
name=postgres
password=postgres

Comment: Эту ошибку я вызвал специально, изменив ключ name на username, чтобы показать эти ромбы. Эта ошибка из-за того что в винде это слово зарезервировано и подставляется имя пользователя пк.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, это ваш кейс https://stackoverflow.com/a/64439968/4558866. Посмотрите сами и отпишитесь потом смогли вы в итоге разобраться или нет. Просто не уверен что будет сегодня время на разбор вашей ситуации и написанию подробного ответа

Comment: там не про кириллицу и не про Win1251, но суть та же

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, с проблемой разобрался!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем с решением помог следующий пост: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586895/psql-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8

У меня в файле postgresql было так:

```
lc_messages = 'Russian_Russia.1251'         
lc_monetary = 'Russian_Russia.1251'         
lc_numeric = 'Russian_Russia.1251'          
lc_time = 'Russian_Russia.1251'             
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.russian'
```

Заменил, как советовали в указанном мной посте.
Так же, на всякий случай, добавил в переменные среды: **LC_MESSAGES = English** (хоть как я понял из доков, при не совпадении значений, основными считаются настройки из файла).
Перезапускаем службу postgresql и теперь ромбики с вопросами исчезли, уступив свое место вменяемому тексту:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Mixa"
```

Comment: Отлично! Держите первый "плюсик"